# How to create MySQL database on existing container

Tags: mysql, docker, centos, containers

My system team send me an information about mysql server container as follow

- Version: MySQL 5.7
- ip: 61.28.x.x
- port: 33066
- username root: root
- pass root: xx

How I create MySQL database and import database file on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the `mysql` command line, specifing all the host/port/password requirements.

```
mysql -h 61.28.x.x -u root -pxx --port 33066
```

Then [CREATE DATABASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html) to create a database. `use {databasename};` to default to that database.

Then [source {filename}](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) to import.

Comment: Please help me the detail for  "Using the mysql command line, specifing all the host/port/password requirements.". 
I have only root user and pass for mysql

Answer (score 0):

I import the database by Workbench.
I am so sorry for response late.
I am so sorry.